# Why doesnt pandas create an excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Im trying to create an excel file with pandas for a database I have generated.

I have tried both:

```
import pandas as pd

# write database to excel
df = pd.DataFrame(database)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('fifa19.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

as well as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(database).T 
df.to_excel('database.xls')
```

However, none of the options generate an excel file. Database is a dictionary.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. The file is created in the current working directory of the interpreter; i.e. the output of `os.getcwd()` -- perhaps you're looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @fuglede You were right. It got saved to a completely different location. Is there a simple way to change that so it saves to the same directory as the file?

Comment: @AntonÖdman You can use `os.chdir` to change the working directory, but depending on how you're using this, chances are that you're better off by specifying the absolute path in the argument to `ExcelWriter`.

Comment: simple `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/home/anton/newoutput.xlsx')` , however you don't need to mention `engine='xlsxwriter'` in the newwer version of pandas.

Comment: @AntonÖdman  , i think its not good to call extra module to change the path even when we can explicitly mention the path during the write of new file until its mandatory for some reasons.

Comment: @pygo: That is also why I'm also saying that he's probably better off by not doing that.

Comment: @fuglede, Sorry, i was suppose to address this  to Anton :) , changed

Answer (score 6):

From the pandas document [Notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) itself:

If passing an existing `ExcelWriter` object, then the sheet will be added to the existing workbook. This can be used to save different DataFrames to one workbook:

```
>>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
# writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/path_to_save/output.xlsx')
>>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
>>> writer.save()
```

> For compatibility with `to_csv`, to_excel serializes lists and dicts to
> strings before writing.

Comment: Thanks for this. The code I had (written by someone else) worked fine for some time, but for some reason stopped working (may have been due to environment changes). Turned out the code didn't have the 'writer.save()' line. Now it works :)